# What does Windows performance counter ASP.NET\Requests Current mean?

Tags: windows, asp.net, performance-counters

In Windows Performance Monitor, I can add a counter named `ASP.NET\Requests Current`. In our application, we use this counter to keep track of whether there are still ongoing requests or whether the VM can reboot. In short, we follow these steps:

1. We remove the VM from the load balancer, preventing new traffic from being sent to it.
2. We wait for `ASP.NET\Requests Current` to reach 0.
3. We reboot the VM.

I have tried to understand exactly what this counter measure, but I keep reading contradicting information. Specifically, I wonder if this counter includes requests which are currently queued but have not yet started to execute?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lawrencegripper/a1561be7eeac433262fd#file-waitforsessions-ps1